# How to stop the execution of a running code in x11

Tags: c, linux, x11, xlib

I have a program that draws on a x11 window and I'd like to quit it as soon as I press any key.

With the code I have, I cannot stop the program with a keypress until the `for` loop has finished drawing on the window (moving a red oval from left to right). I'd like to quit the `for` loop as soon as a key is pressed regardless of the state of the drawing (finished or not) even if the `for` loop hasn't finished executing its part.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>
#include <unistd.h>

Display *dis;
Window win;

unsigned long GetColor(char *color_name)
{
  Colormap cmap;
  XColor near_color, true_color;
  cmap = DefaultColormap(dis, 0);
  XAllocNamedColor(dis, cmap, color_name, &near_color, &true_color);
  return(near_color.pixel);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  if ((dis = XOpenDisplay(NULL)) == NULL) { printf("Error XOpenDisplay\n"); return 1; }

  win = XCreateSimpleWindow(dis, RootWindow(dis, 0), 1, 1, 256, 256, 0, BlackPixel(dis, 0), BlackPixel(dis, 0));

  XSelectInput(dis, win, ExposureMask | KeyPressMask | KeyReleaseMask);

  XMapWindow(dis, win);
  XFlush(dis);

  XEvent ev;
  do {
    XNextEvent(dis, &ev);
  } while (ev.type != Expose);

  GC gc;
  gc = XCreateGC(dis, DefaultRootWindow(dis), 0, 0);
  XSetFunction(dis, gc, GXxor);

  while (!(XCheckWindowEvent(dis, win, KeyPressMask, &ev) || XCheckTypedWindowEvent(dis, win, ClientMessage, &ev))) {

    XNextEvent(dis, &ev);

    // quit program as soon as a key is pressed
    if (ev.type == KeyPress && XEventsQueued(dis, QueuedAfterReading)) {
      goto finish;
    }
    // I'd like to quit from this for loop as soon as a key is pressed
    for (int t = 0; t < 150; t++) {

      // quit program as soon as a key is pressed
      if (ev.type == KeyPress && XEventsQueued(dis, QueuedAfterReading)) {
        goto finish;
      } else {
        // draw a red oval and move it from left to right
        XSetForeground(dis, gc, BlackPixel(dis, 0) ^ GetColor("red"));
        XFillArc(dis, win, gc, t * 5 + 10, t * 3 + 40, 80, 40, 0, 360 * 64);
        XSetForeground(dis, gc, BlackPixel(dis, 0) ^ GetColor("red"));
        usleep(20000);
        XFillArc(dis, win, gc, t * 5 + 10, t * 3 + 40, 80, 40, 0, 360 * 64);
        //XSync(dis, True);
      }
    }
  }

finish:
  XFreeGC(dis, gc);
  XDestroyWindow(dis, win);
  XCloseDisplay(dis);
  return(0);
}
```

I execute it with:
`gcc draw.c -lX11 && ./a.out`

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are facing has to do with `usleep`.

Basically, `usleep` will suspend the thread that the program runs on until the set interval will finish. You can interrupt it by sending a signal (e.g. `SIGKILL` or `SIGQUIT`) to it, but this is something that can be done only outside of the program, not from within.

You may want to see [this page](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/3p-usleep/) to understand how `usleep` works.